# SQL: Getting maximum number of files download on which day

Tags: mysql, sql

I got confused in writing a sql query for getting the date and the total maximum number of files downloaded on which day.

My table contain 3 fields `sno` , `da_te` , `fileName`, maybe there is no need of `fileName` in this situation.
`sno` is in integer, `da_te` is in default timestamp, `fileName` in varchar

so for example my table looks like this:-

```
sno    da_te                                    fileName

 1        2015-10-18 11:13:00                      xyz.pdf   
 2        2015-10-18 11:13:00                      xxy.pdf
 3        2015-10-18 11:13:00                      xyy.pdf
 4        2015-10-18 11:13:00                      yyz.pdf
 5        2015-10-18 11:13:00                      xyz.pdf
 6        2015-10-17 11:13:00                      xzz.pdf
 7        2015-10-17 11:13:00                      zyz.pdf
 8        2015-10-17 11:13:00                      xyx.pdf
 9        2015-10-16 11:13:00                      xyy.pdf
10        2015-10-16 11:13:00                      xyz.pdf
```

So, in result we can get:-

Maximum Number of files downloaded = 5

and the date max file download is = 2015-10-18

i want to know how to write the sql query for above situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` with `count`.

```
select date(da_te), count(*)
from tablename
group by date(da_te)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I have one more query that, if I want the one date from every month with maximum number of files download in that month. Means if I have record of last 5 month and I want to show the single date of each and every 5 months with maximum number of files downloaded. So, in result we can get total 5 records having the date with max download with respect to there corresponding months.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the date portion of your datetime column

```
select date(da_te), count(*)
from  mytable
group by date(da_te) order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I have one more query that, if I want the one date from every month with maximum number of files download in that month. Means if I have record of last 5 month and I want to show the single date of each and every 5 months with maximum number of files downloaded. So, in result we can get total 5 records having the date with max download with respect to there corresponding months.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        @n := @n+1,
        z.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATE(da_te),
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            YOURTABLE
        GROUP BY
            DATE(DA_TE)
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(*) DESC
    ) z,
    (SELECT @n := 0) v
) x
WHERE n = 1;
```

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'n' in 'where clause'`
I run your query but is shows this error

Comment: and when i placed `@` in last line as `WHERE @n = 1;` then query get execute and shows no result, instead it remains on the same sql query page.

Comment: Change the where clause to WHERE v = 1;